# Regression on "horizontal" dataseries in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a pd.dataframe that looks like

| rwIndex | ... | colX1 ... colXn | ... | colY1 ...colYn | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rwA | ... | Ax1...Axn | ... | Ay1...Ayn | ... |
| rwB | ... | Bx1...Bxn | ... | By1...Bn | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| rwZ | ... | Zx1...Zxn | ... | Zy1...Zn | ... |

and I want to run lin regression "by row"

that is for each row do linear regression of [y1,...,yn] vs [x1,...xn]

in order to produce something like

| rwIndex | ... | colX1 ... colXn | ... | colY1 ...colYn | linRegressionCoefs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rwA | ... | Ax1...Axn | ... | Ay1...Ayn | listCoefsA |
| rwB | ... | Bx1...Bxn | ... | By1...Bn | listCoefsB |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| rwZ | ... | Zx1...Zxn | ... | Zy1...Zn | listCoefsZ |

It looks like that the usual skl, np regressors are designed to work for data series in columns. So before I start transposing & selecting datasubsets, how would you approach this one ?

Comment: could you just transpose the dataframe with `df.T`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.